# class has no member problem (code works find in VS, but failed in Ubuntu)

Tags: class, undefined, member, identifier

all 
I got a piece of code about sparse matrix, it works fine in VISUAL STUDIO 2008, but when I want to port it to ubuntu environment, the compiler report the following errors:

> ../include/spmatrix.h(123): error:
>   class template "numc::CSRMatrix"
>   has no member "resize"
>
> ../include/spmatrix.h(170): error:
>   expected a ";"
>
> ../include/spmatrix.h(171): error:
>   identifier "it" is undefined
>
> ../include/spmatrix.h(176): error:
>   expected a ";"
>
> ../include/spmatrix.h(178): error:
>   identifier "it" is undefined
>
> ../include/spmatrix.h(183): error:
>   identifier "size" is undefined
>
> ../include/spmatrix.h(185): error:
>   expected a ";"
>
> ../include/spmatrix.h(185): error:
>   identifier "it" is undefined
>
> .> ./include/spmatrix.h(186): error:
>   expected a ";"
>
> ../include/spmatrix.h(187): error:
>   identifier "cit" is undefined
>
> ../include/spmatrix.h(205): error:
>   expected a ";"
>
> ../include/spmatrix.h(205): error:
>   identifier "it" is undefined
>
> ../include/spmatrix.h(218): error:
>   expected a ";"
>
> ../include/spmatrix.h(218): error:
>   identifier "it" is undefined
>
> ../include/spmatrix.h(222): error:
>   expected a ";"
>
> ../include/spmatrix.h(223): error:
>   identifier "f" is undefined
>
> ../include/spmatrix.h(224): error:
>   identifier "make_pair" is undefined
>
> ../include/spmatrix.h(224): error:
>   type name is not allowed
>
> ../include/spmatrix.h(224): error:
>   type name is not allowed
>
> ../include/spmatrix.h(245): error:
>   identifier "RowType" is undefined
>
> ../include/spmatrix.h(246): error:
>   name followed by "::" must be a class
>   or namespace name
>
> ../include/spmatrix.h(246): error:
>   expected a ";"
>
> ../include/spmatrix.h(246): error:
>   identifier "it" is undefined
>
> ../include/spmatrix.h(269): error:
>   identifier "RowType" is undefined
>
> ../include/spmatrix.h(270): error:
>   name followed by "::" must be a class
>   or namespace name
>
> ../include/spmatrix.h(270): error:
>   expected a ";"
>
> ../include/spmatrix.h(271): error:
>   identifier "it" is undefined
>
> ../include/spmatrix.h(276): error:
>   identifier "RowType" is undefined
>
> ../include/spmatrix.h(276): error:
>   identifier "crow" is undefined
>
> ../include/spmatrix.h(277): error:
>   name followed by "::" must be a class
>   or namespace name
>
> ../include/spmatrix.h(277): error:
>   expected a ";"
>
> ../include/spmatrix.h(279): error:
>   identifier "it" is undefined
>
> ../include/spmatrix.h(311): error:
>   expected a ";"
>
> ../include/spmatrix.h(311): error:
>   identifier "it" is undefined
>
> ../include/spmatrix.h(350): error:
>   expected a ";"
>
> ../include/spmatrix.h(350): error:
>   identifier "it" is undefined
>
> ../include/spmatrix.h(423): error:
>   expected a ";"
>
> ../include/spmatrix.h(424): error:
>   identifier "it" is undefined
>
> ../include/spmatrix.h(484): error:
>   expected a ";"
>
> ../include/spmatrix.h(485): error:
>   identifier "it" is undefined
>
> ../include/spmatrix.h(518): error:
>   expected a ";"
>
> ../include/spmatrix.h(520): error:
>   identifier "it" is undefined

I try to figure out where the problem is, but failed. Hope you can give me some hint where the problem is. Thanks in advance for your help!

Below is the code of this sparse matrix, it is just a header file:

```
#pragma   warning(disable:   4786)

#ifndef NUMC_CSRMATRIX_H
#define NUMC_CSRMATRIX_H

#include <cmath>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <limits>
#include <algorithm>

#ifndef _NUMC_BEGIN
#define _NUMC_BEGIN namespace numc {
#define _NUMC_END   }
#endif

_NUMC_BEGIN
using std::vector;
using std::map;
using std::swap;
using std::lower_bound;

template<typename R> class CSRMatrix;
template<typename R> struct RowMat;
template<typename R> void CreateCSRMatrixFromRowMap(CSRMatrix<R>&, const RowMat<R>&);
t    emplate<typename R> void CSRMatrixTranspose (const CSRMatrix<R>&, CSRMatrix<R>&);
template<typename R> bool Mul2MatricesSymmResult (const CSRMatrix<R>&, const CSRMatrix<R>&, RowMat<R>&);
template<typename R> bool Mul2MatricesSymmResult (const CSRMatrix<R>&, const CSRMatrix<R>&, CSRMatrix<R>&);
template<typename R> bool Mul2Matrices (const CSRMatrix<R>&, const CSRMatrix<R>&, RowMat<R>&);
template<typename R> bool Mul2Matrices (const CSRMatrix<R>&, const CSRMatrix<R>&, CSRMatrix<R>&);

template<typename R>
class CSRMatrix
{
public:
    enum MatType{ RealStrucSymm=1, RealSymmPosDef=2, RealSymmIndef=-2, 
        CompStrucSymm=3, CompHermPosDef=4, CompHermIndef=-4, 
        CompSymm=6, RealUnSymm=11, CompUnSymm=13};

    std::vector<R> mAv;
    std::vector<int> mAi, mAj;

    CSRMatrix():mNRow(0),mNCol(0),mMtype(RealUnSymm) {};
    CSRMatrix(const RowMat<R> &rm):mMtype(RealUnSymm)   { CreateCSRMatrixFromRowMap(*this, rm); }
    MatType mMtype;

#if ( defined(_MSC_VER)&&(_MSC_VER>1300) )
    //template<typename T> class CSRMatrix;
#define FFM <>  // FFM FRIEND_FUNCTION_MAGIC
#else
#define FFM
#endif

    friend void CreateCSRMatrixFromRowMap FFM(CSRMatrix<R>&, const RowMat<R>&);
    friend void CSRMatrixTranspose FFM(const CSRMatrix<R>&, CSRMatrix<R>&);
    friend bool Mul2MatricesSymmResult FFM(const CSRMatrix<R>&, const CSRMatrix<R>&, RowMat<R>&);
    friend bool Mul2MatricesSymmResult FFM(const CSRMatrix<R>&, const CSRMatrix<R>&, CSRMatrix<R>&);
    friend bool Mul2Matrices FFM(const CSRMatrix<R>&, const CSRMatrix<R>&, RowMat<R>&);
    friend bool Mul2Matrices FFM(const CSRMatrix<R>&, const CSRMatrix<R>&, CSRMatrix<R>&);

#undef FFM

private:
    int mNRow, mNCol;

public:
    inline int nRow() const { return mNRow; }
    inline int nCol() const { return mNCol; }
    inline int empty() const { return (0==nRow() || 0==nCol()) ;}
        inline bool onebase() const { return (!mAi.empty()) && (mAi[0]==1); }       //default: zerobase, including empty matrix!
    inline MatType mtype() const { return mMtype; }

    inline bool issymm() const
    { return (RealSymmIndef==mMtype || RealSymmPosDef==mMtype || CompSymm==mMtype); }

    inline void clear() 
    { mNRow = 0; mNCol = 0; mMtype = RealUnSymm; mAv.clear(); mAi.clear(); mAj.clear(); }

    R getElementV(int x, int y) const{
        double *p = const_cast<CSRMatrix*>(this)->getElementP(x, y);
        return (NULL==p)?0:*p;  
    }

    R* getElementP(int x, int y) {
        if (x<0||y<0)   return NULL;
        if ( issymm() && x>y) swap(x, y);
        const int off = onebase();
        std::vector<int>::const_iterator it = lower_bound(mAj.begin()+mAi[x]-off, mAj.begin()+(mAi[x+1]-off), y+off);
        if (it==mAj.begin()+(mAi[x+1]-off) || *it!=(y+off) ) return NULL;

        return &mAv.front() + ( it-mAj.begin() );
    }

    void MultiVect(R* in, R *out) const;

    bool ChangeBase(bool oneBase) {
        if( onebase() == oneBase )  return true;
        int ii;
        if (oneBase) {
            if (mAi[0] != 0){
                fprintf(stderr, "error matrix!");
                return false;
            }

            for (ii=0; ii<mAi.back(); ii++) mAj[ii]++;

            for (ii=0; ii<mNRow+1; ii++) mAi[ii]++;
        }
        else {
            if (mAi[0] != 1){
                fprintf(stderr, "error matrix!");
                return false;
            }

            for (ii=0; ii<mAi.back()-1; ii++) mAj[ii]--;

            for (ii=0; ii<mNRow+1; ii++) mAi[ii]--;
        }
        return true;
    }

    void GetSubMat(const std::vector<int> &xi, const std::vector<int> &yi, CSRMatrix& mat){
        mat.resize( yi.size() );
        for(int j=0; j<yi.size(); j++){
            for(int i=0; i<xi.size(); i++){

            }
        }

    }

    void print(FILE *f=stdout){
        fprintf(f, "The matrix:\n");
        for(int i=0; i<nRow(); i++){
            fprintf(f, "%2d#:", i);
            for(int j=0; j<nCol(); j++) {
                fprintf(f, "\t%.3e", getElementV(i, j) );
            }
            fprintf(f, "\n");
        }
    }

};

template<typename R>
struct RowMat:public vector<map<int, R> >
{
    typedef map<int, R> RowType;
    typedef vector<RowType> BaseType;
    int mNCol;

    RowMat(int nrow=0, int ncol=0):BaseType(nrow),mNCol(ncol)   { }
    ~RowMat()   { }
    RowMat(const CSRMatrix<R> &mat)
    {
        resize(mat.nCol(), mat.nRow());

        int off = mat.onebase()?1:0;
        for(unsigned int i=0; i+1<mat.mAi.size(); i++){
            for(int j=mat.mAi[i]; j<mat.mAi[i+1]; j++){
                (*this)(i, mat.mAj[j-off]-off) = mat.mAv[ j-off ];
            }
        }

    }

    virtual bool symmetric() const {return false;}
    virtual inline R operator()(int i, int j) const{
        const RowType &crow = (*this)[i];
        RowType::const_iterator it = crow.find(j);
        return ( it==crow.end() )?0:it->second;
    }

    virtual inline R& operator()(int i, int j){
        RowType &crow = (*this)[i];
        RowType::iterator it = crow.find(j);

        return ( it==crow.end() )?crow.insert( std::pair<int,R>(j, 0) ).first->second:it->second;
    }

    int clearZero() {
        int nZero;
        for (size_t i=0; i<size(); i++) {
            RowType &r = (*this)[i];
            for (RowType::const_iterator it=r.begin(); it!=r.end(); ) {
                RowType::const_iterator cit = it++;
                if(fabs(cit->second) < std::numeric_limits<R>::epsilon()){
                    r.erase(cit);
                    ++nZero;
                }
            }
        }
        return nZero;
    }

    inline void resize(int nrow, int ncol=0) { BaseType::resize(nrow); mNCol = ncol>0?ncol:mNCol; }
    inline int nRow()   const { return BaseType::size(); }
    inline int nCol()   const { return mNCol; }

    int operator+=(const RowMat<R>& r) { return add(r, 1); }

    void operator *= (const double v) {
        for(int i=0; i<nRow(); i++){
            map<int, R>& crow = (*this)[i];
            for(map<int,R>::iterator it=crow.begin(); it!=crow.end(); ++it){
                it->second *= v;
            }
        }
    }

    int add(const RowMat<R>& r, R k){
        const int h = nRow();
        if( r.nRow() != h ) return -1;

        for(int i=0; i<h; i++){
            const map<int, R>& rrow = r[i];
            map<int, R>& lrow = (*this)[i];
            for(RowType::const_iterator it=rrow.begin(); it!=rrow.end(); ++it){
                int col = it->first;
                R val = it->second * k;

                map<int,R>::iterator f = lrow.find(col);
                if( f != lrow.end() )   f->second += val;
                lrow.insert( make_pair<int, R>(col, val) );
            }
        }

        return 0;
    }

};

template<typename R>
struct RowMatSym : public RowMat<R>
{
    typedef RowMat<R> Base;

    RowMatSym(int nrow=0, int ncol=0):Base(nrow, ncol)  {}
    ~RowMatSym()    { }

    RowMatSym(const RowMat<R> &rm){
        resize(rm.nCol(), rm.nRow());

        for(unsigned int i=0; i<rm.nRow(); i++){
            const RowType &crow = rm[i];
            for(RowType::const_iterator it=crow.begin(); it!=crow.end(); ++it){
                (*this)(i, it->first) = it->second;
            }
        }
    }

    RowMatSym(const CSRMatrix<R> &mat)
    {
        resize(mat.nCol(), mat.nRow());

        int off = mat.onebase()?1:0;
        for(unsigned int i=0; i+1<mat.mAi.size(); i++){
            for(int j=mat.mAi[i]; j<mat.mAi[i+1]; j++){
                const int k = mat.mAj[j-off]-off;
                (*this)(i, k) = mat.mAv[ j-off ];
            }
        }
    }

    virtual bool symmetric() const {return true;}

    inline R operator()(int i, int j) const{
        if(i>j) std::swap(i, j);
        const RowType &crow = (*this)[i];
        RowType::const_iterator it = crow.find(j);
        return ( it==crow.end() )?0:it->second;
    }

    inline R& operator()(int i, int j){
        if(i>j) std::swap(i, j);
        RowType &crow = (*this)[i];
        RowType::iterator it = crow.find(j);

        return ( it==crow.end() )?crow.insert( std::pair<int,R>(j, 0) ).first->second
            :it->second;
    }

};


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/// Get SubMatrix from rowmap
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
template <typename R>
void GetSubRowMap(const RowMat<R>& src,
                  const std::vector<int> &xi, const std::vector<int> &yi,
                  RowMat<R>& dst)
{
    assert( xi.size()>0 && yi.size()>0 );
    assert( yi.back() < (int)src.size() );
    if( xi.empty() || yi.empty() || yi.back() >= (int)src.size() ){
        fprintf(stderr, "\nerror matrix!");
        return;
    }


    typedef std::map<int, R> row;
    dst.resize( yi.size() );

    for(unsigned int j=0; j<yi.size(); j++){
        const row &srow = src[ yi[j] ];
        row &drow = dst[j];

        const int* pxi = &xi.front();

        for(row::const_iterator it=srow.begin(); it!=srow.end(); ++it ){
            pxi = std::lower_bound(pxi, &xi.back(), it->first);

            if(*pxi != it->first){          // done
                continue;
            }

            int col = pxi - &xi.front();
            drow[col] = it->second;
        }
    }
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/// Create CSR matrix from vector of rowmap
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
template <typename R>
void CreateCSRMatrixFromRowMap(CSRMatrix<R> &matC, const RowMat<R>& rowC)
{
    if(rowC.mNCol <= 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "\nnumber of column not specified in the RowMat, exit!");
        return;
    }
    matC.clear();
    matC.mNRow = rowC.nRow();
    matC.mNCol = rowC.nCol();

    matC.mAi.reserve(matC.nRow()+1);
    int i,nnz=0;
    for (i=0; i<matC.nRow(); i++) {
        nnz += rowC[i].size();
    }
    matC.mAj.reserve(nnz);
    matC.mAv.reserve(nnz);

    // copy rows into matC
    matC.mAi.push_back(0);
    for (i=0; i<matC.nRow(); i++) {
        matC.mAi.push_back(matC.mAi.back());
        for (std::map<int, R>::const_iterator it=rowC[i].begin(); it!=rowC[i].end(); it++) {
            matC.mAi.back()++;
            matC.mAj.push_back(it->first);
            matC.mAv.push_back(it->second);
        }
    }
}


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/// Computes the transpose of a matrix.
template <typename R>
void CSRMatrixTranspose(const CSRMatrix<R> &matA, CSRMatrix<R> &matAT)
{
    if (matA.issymm()) {        // symmetric - just copy the matrix
        matAT = matA;
        return;
        }

    matAT.mNRow = matA.nCol();
    matAT.mNCol = matA.nRow();
    matAT.mMtype = matA.mMtype;

    // non-symmetric matrix -> need to build data structure.
    // we'll go over the columns and build the rows
    int off = matA.onebase()?1:0;
    RowMat<R> rowC(matA.nCol(), matA.nRow());
    for (int i=0; i<matA.nRow(); i++) {
        for (int j=matA.mAi[i]; j<matA.mAi[i+1]; j++) {
            rowC[matA.mAj[j-off]-off][i] = matA.mAv[j-off];
        }
    }

    CreateCSRMatrixFromRowMap(matAT, rowC);
}


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// multiplication of sparse matrix
// Assuming nothing about the result (the result is not stored symmetric)
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
template <typename R>
bool Mul2Matrices(const CSRMatrix<R> &matA, const CSRMatrix<R> &matB,
                  RowMat<R> &rowsC)
{
    if(matA.onebase() || matB.onebase() ){
        fprintf(stderr, "\nmatrix saved in 1-based format, pleased converted it to 0-based and try again!");
        return false;
    }
    // Compatibility of dimensions
    if (matA.nCol() != matB.nRow())
        return false;

    // (m x n)*(n x k) = (m x k)
    const int m=matA.nRow();
    const int n=matA.nCol();
    const int k=matB.nCol();

    rowsC = RowMat<R>(m, k);    // clean all coefficients

    R aiv, valB;
    int colInd, colB;

    for (int i=0; i<m; ++i) {                   // creating row i of C
        std::map<int, R> &mapRow2Val = rowsC[i];
        for (int iAi = matA.mAi[i]; iAi < matA.mAi[i+1]; ++iAi) {           // travel on ai
            colInd = matA.mAj[iAi];
            aiv = matA.mAv[iAi];
            // make aiv*b_{rowInd} and insert into mapRow2Val
            for (int iB=matB.mAi[colInd]; iB<matB.mAi[colInd+1]; ++iB) {
                colB=matB.mAj[iB];
                valB=matB.mAv[iB];
                // insert valA*aiv into map
                std::map<int, R>::iterator it = mapRow2Val.find(colB);
                if (it == mapRow2Val.end()) {       // first time
                    mapRow2Val[colB] = valB*aiv;
                }
                else {
                    it->second = it->second + valB*aiv;
                }
            }
        }
    }// now column i is created

    return true;
}

template <typename R>
bool Mul2Matrices(const CSRMatrix<R> &matA, const CSRMatrix<R> &matB, CSRMatrix<R> &matC)
{
    RowMat<R> rowsC;
    if( !Mul2Matrices(matA, matB, rowsC) ) return false;

    const int k=matB.mNCol;
    rowsC.mNCol = k;
    CreateCSRMatrixFromRowMap(matC, rowsC);                     // modified by jianwei hu @ 16/09/07
    return true;
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// multiplication of sparse matrix
// The result is symmetric
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
template <typename R>
bool Mul2MatricesSymmResult(const CSRMatrix<R> &matA, const CSRMatrix<R> &matB,
                            RowMat<R> &rowsC)
{
    if(matA.onebase() || matB.onebase()){
        fprintf(stderr, "\nmatrix saved in 1-based format, pleased converted it to 0-based and try again!");
        return false;
    }
    // Compatibility of dimensions
    if(matA.nCol() != matB.nRow() || matA.nRow() != matB.nCol())    return false;

    // (m x n)*(n x m) = (m x m)
    const int m=matA.nRow();
    const int n=matA.nCol();

    rowsC = RowMat<R>(m, m);    // clean all coefficients

    R aiv, valB;
    int colInd, colB;

    for(int i=0; i<m; ++i) {                    // creating row i of C
        std::map<int, R> &mapRow2Val = rowsC[i];
        for (int iAi = matA.mAi[i]; iAi < matA.mAi[i+1]; ++iAi) {           // travel on ai
            colInd = matA.mAj[iAi];
            aiv = matA.mAv[iAi];
            // make aiv*b_{colInd} and insert into mapRow2Val
            for (int iB=matB.mAi[colInd]; iB<matB.mAi[colInd+1]; ++iB) {
                colB=matB.mAj[iB];
                if (colB >= i) {
                    valB=matB.mAv[iB];
                    // insert valA*aiv into map
                    std::map<int, R>::iterator it = mapRow2Val.find(colB);
                    if (it == mapRow2Val.end()) {       // first time
                        mapRow2Val[colB] = valB*aiv;
                    }
                    else {
                        it->second = it->second + valB*aiv;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }// now column i is created

    return true;
}

template <typename R>
bool Mul2MatricesSymmResult(const CSRMatrix<R> &matA, const CSRMatrix<R> &matB, CSRMatrix<R> &matC)
{
    RowMat<R> rowsC;
    if( !Mul2MatricesSymmResult(matA, matB, rowsC) )    return false;

    rowsC.mNCol = matA.nCol();
    CreateCSRMatrixFromRowMap(matC, rowsC);
    matC.mMtype = CSRMatrix<R>::RealSymmIndef;
    return true;
}


template<typename R>
void DebugShowRowMatrix(const std::vector<std::map<int,R> > &rowA)
{
    printf("\n");
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<rowA.size(); i++){
        printf("\n%3d#", i);
        std::map<int,R>::const_iterator it=rowA[i].begin();
        int j=0;
        for(; it!=rowA[i].end(); ++it){
            for(int k=j; k<it->first; k++){
                printf("\t%3.2f", 0);
            }

            j=it->first+1;
            printf("\t%3.2f", it->second);
        }
    }
}

typedef CSRMatrix<float> CSRMatrixf;
typedef CSRMatrix<double> CSRMatrixd;


_NUMC_END

#endif      // NUMC_CSRMATRIX_H
```

Answer (score 0):

Line 123: the CSRMatrix::resize method is undefined, and since CSRMatrix has no base class, it's not inherited.

Line 171: Using a typedef's nested type, like RowType::const_iterator, is a Visual Studio extension, it may not work in other compilers. You should replace these and similar usages with other typedefs, like so:

```
typedef typename map<int,R>::const_iterator RowTypeConstIterator;
```

UPDATE: The typename keyword **is** required (just learned it!)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. But.... resize() is defined in a struct, line 123 however is defined in a class. How to move the declaration before the definition?

Comment: Meanwhile, this code works fine in vs2008. I wonder why it works on vs, instead on ubuntu?

Comment: 1) Sorry, my bad. On a closer look, there is no definition for the CSRMatrix::resize method. In the struct it works because it extends std::vector. Wonder how this compiles ok on VS, perhaps I'm missing something. 2) I believe you are using another compiler, most surely g++. Though most of the language features are the same throughout different compilers, some offer extensions which others don't. Not sure which feature is the problem in your case.

Comment: HI,I also notice the first problem, thus I eliminate the function call resize. But there is still some problem remians, that is, "identifier it is undefined" problem, but actually it has been defined to RowType. I don't know why compiler always throw errors. Thanks~

Comment: Aha, there's a problem: RowType is a typedef. Some compilers (Visual Studio's) realize that RowType is a std::map and let you use its nested type const_iterator, but others are stricter and don't let you do that. Try replacing RowType::const_iterator and anything similar with a typedef for each, like this: typedef map<int,R>::const_iterator RowTypeConstIterator, and use that instead

Comment: Thansk, dario. I've found part of the solution, for template argument dependent name, the 'typename' keyword is needed in front of it. For example: map<int, R>::iterator is not allowed, instead, you have to use like this 'typename map<int,R>::iterator' then it works. But I still have a problem, that is although, struct RowMatSym inherit from RowMat, but the member function of RowMat still can't be found by compiler.....Can you help me figure out where the problem is?

Comment: If you mean the call to size() in line 186, you can solve it by calling the base class's version ( vector<map<int, R> >::size() ). By the way, I got your whole code compiling under IDE One (an online compiler, it seems to use g++ like you do). Here it is: http://ideone.com/EGjIA